# How to set the resolution of bitmap fonts in XeTex?

Tags: fonts, bitmap, xetex

I would like to use the Calibri font for text and the concmath font for math. The latter is a bitmapped font and therefore it is rendered with rough edges by default. In pdflatex, one can set the resolution of the bitmapped font using (for example)

```
\pdfpkmode={linolttz}
\pdfpkresolution=3386
```

But this doesn't work in XeLatex which I need in order to use Calibri.

Is there a similar command in XeLatex for changing the resolution of bitmapped fonts?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your post was migrated here from another Stack Exchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: By the way, it's quite interesting. It appears that `(x)dvipdfmx` can only set the resolution, but not the MF mode.